# How to make stairs with a flat bottom

Tags: modifiers, topology

I'm trying to make a procedural staircase using an array and solidify modifier. I created two planes (a rise and a run) like this:
[image: Base Geometry for Individual Stair]

Then apply the array with a relative offset of 1 in the Y and Z directions and solidify everything into a staircase that looks like this:
[image: Modifiers Applied to Starting Planes]

I would like to be able to generate a watertight mesh after applying the modifiers with the underside of the staircase being one single face (instead of the zigzag I've found in every other tutorial). I may be going about this entirely wrong as I think like a Sketchup user but here is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Intended Result]

**Is there a way to do this non-destructively where the rise and run, stair count, and flat bottom can all be controlled parametrically and independent of each other?**

I had to apply the modifiers and still couldn't come up with a clean mesh for the example image above. I still couldn't come up with a clean topology, and it broke my mirrored staircase on the other side:
[image: Failed Attempt]

Comment: Hi :). Give it some time and @Chris will bring his geometry nodes and build your whole house :))

Comment: love you Jachym!!!!! :D

Comment: @Jachym not _enough_ time, at that, for slowcoaches like me to slot in an answer!

Comment: @ Robin Betts, you can still give the Python answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you are:

result:

[image]

node setup:

[image]

[image]

if you add a realize instance node before the output and apply it, you won't get one single face on the downside (sorry for that), but a pretty clean topology:

[image]

The step node just creates this:

[image]

a box and the two vertices will be just pushed on the x axis.

[image]

the mesh line instances the steps in z direction. With the indentation value i push the vertices and at the same time move the instances on the x axis so that it fits.

[image]

maybe you are asking: is this all it can do?

well...no...you can add e.g. a simple deform modifier, and you get this:

[image]

if you change the step node to this:

[image]

you can build stairs for your basement:

[image]

so with negative height you now get downstairs :D

Comment: ok you've made a stairs that goes up but are you able to make a stairs that goes down? I need one for my basement

Comment: @moonboots: challenge accepted!

Comment: answer updated!! :D

Comment: wow great, thanks a lot! but actually I was just kidding, I don't need any stairs in my spaceships

Comment: @moonboots I thought you said he was lazy :)

Comment: @Robin Betts, he is, at first he wanted to model an escalator

Comment: Beautiful, simple and robust; you are incredible my friend. This was my first question thanks for being a great community y'all!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 11):

It seems I'm a bit late, but here's my Geometry Nodes entry with all your criteria satisfied, including optional start/end steps and perfectly manifold geometry:

[image]

To get a manifold geometry I had to forgo using steps as instances and tried drawing the side section of the whole staircase edge by edge, and extruded the finished profile in one go instead:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That’s great! +1

Answer (score 4):

Here's a non-node approach.
Create a subdivided plane as shown below 
[image]

First join, with <kbd>J</kbd>, the verts cirlced then select, with <kbd>B</kbd> to make it faster, faces as shown

Remove the selected faces and Y-extrude

[image]

Comment: i just wonder for the upvotes here if the OP ask for a procedural (non destructive) solution....but yeah....